# Show that if $n$ points are such that any three lie in a circle of radius $1$, then all of them lie in a circle of radius $1$

Tags: geometry, induction, circles, plane-geometry

Consider a set of $n$ points in the plane such that any three of them are contained in a circle with radius $r=1$. Prove by induction that all $n$ points are contained in a circle with radius $r=1$.

Comment: You have to assume $n \ge 3$.  The statement is false for $n=2$ (unless you allow "any three" to allow a repeated point).

Comment: That is true, I think we can assume a point can be repeated.

Answer (score 3):

If any three of the $n$ points are contained in a circle with radius $r=1$, then the distance between any two of the $n$ points is at most $d=2$. Hence the diameter of the $n$ points as a set is at most $2$. In particular they are contained in a circle of diameter $2$, which has radius $r=1$.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if it is possible to use this idea using induction?

Comment: "Hence the diameter of the n points as a set is at most 2." I don't see how that follows from any two points being at most 2 apart. The vertices of an equilateral triangle with side length 2  does not fit inside a circle of diameter 2. (Sorry, I only just noticed this is an old post that got bumped.)

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I think the doubtful statement is rather "In particular they are contained in a circle of diameter 2".

Comment: @user You're right, it is the fitting in a d=2 circle that is the problematic bit.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I wonder that during 4.5 years nobody noted this flaw. :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider an "envelope" of the points, which form a convex polygon. We choose the maximum angle of a convex polygon. We describe a circle around the three neighboring вершина that form the angle. All the other points will lie within this circle.

Comment: You have not shown that this circle has diameter of at most $2$. In fact, the vertices of the convex hull most likely do not all lie on the boundary of the diameter $2$ circle we are looking for.